# bootstrap the tooltips of the disabled element can't show in the right position

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to add a tooltip to a disabled element, I know it needs a `div`, but that doesn't appear in the right position.
[See description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DG9X2.png)

The picture above shows that the tooltip doesn't appear at the top of the disabled button. How can I resolve that?

Here is the code for the tooltip:

```
<div data-toggle="tooltip" title="disabled Tooltip">
  <button class="btn btn-default" disabled type="button"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer using a fake div wrapper to trigger tooltip event.

```js
$(function () {
  //select the class to toggle the tooltip
  $('.custom-wrapper').tooltip();
})
```

```css
.custom-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20%;
}

.custom-wrapper .btn[disabled] {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.custom-wrapper.disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <br>
  <div class="custom-wrapper disabled" title="I'm disabled">
    <button class="btn btn-default" disabled>button disabled</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your code above is working but you don't have to add a div where you put your tooltip data, you can directly inject it inside your button. Now, looking on your button, It won't fire an event such as tooltip because of the disabled attribute. Remove the disabled attribute and just use it inside the `class` and you're good to go.

> Remember: Events won't fire on disabled elements.

Change

```
<button class="btn btn-default" disabled type="button"></button>
```

To this

```
<button class="btn btn-default disabled" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hi I am disabled"></button>
```

Comment: but in the [document of the bootstrap](http://v3.bootcss.com/javascript/#tooltips),it said Tooltips on disabled elements require wrapper elements
To add a tooltip to a disabled or .disabled element, put the element inside of a <div> and apply the tooltip to that <div> instead.

Comment: @owen-yu, Yes! it's coz it won't work if no wrapper. Giving a wrapper fakes a disabled button so that events will fire. make sense?

Comment: i'm very glad to you answer my questions , could you show me the code using wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default disabled" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on bottom</button>
```

JS

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

Codepen:

http://codepen.io/swapnaranjitanayak/pen/YppoqP

Comment: you add `class="disabled"`,if i want to add the `disabled` attribute to the button ,what can i do?